# Whole site is https:// but now need to make the homepage only http:// - causing redirect loop when i go to https://domain.com

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

Browsed the whole site and can't really find a fix for my issue.

My whole site was `https://`, `http://www.domain`, `http://domain` would redirect to           https://domain.com and then the whole site would run as `https://smoothly`.

I now need to make my homepage only, http:// because of a script I use that won't load    on chrome because it's uses some http:// links, I cannot change the script so my only fix is to make my homepage http:// and then the rest, including all inner pages, automatically become https://

Here's what my htaccess looks like:

```
        rewriteengine on
        #rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
        #rewriterule ^$ "http\:\/\/domain\.com\/" [R=301,L] #528a28c9588af

        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
        RewriteRule (^$) http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L] 

        RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
        RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

        #RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
        #RewriteRule ^(|/)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]



        rewritecond $0                  !^(index\.php|front_assets|images|captcha|css|js|editor|assets|robots\.txt)
       rewriterule ^.*$ index.php [L]


This is pretty bad but some of it works, it redirects the http://www homepage to   http:// which is what i want, it also redirects https:// www. domain .com to http:// homepage which is what i want, but when i go to https:// domain .com it redirects to http:// homepage but gives a redirect loop version.

 Basically what I want is to make     http:// www . domain .com, https:// domain .com and https:// www . domain.com to redirect to http:// domain.com

 and then once we're on     http:// domain .com, if you click on anything or go to any inner pages I want it to show the https version, i just need the homepage to be http: //
```

Can anyone help, been trying to do this for days with no luck.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HOST_NAME}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^.+$ https://%{HOST_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $0 !^(index\.php|front_assets|images|captcha|css|js|editor|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```